# Value initialization of class object without default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer

I am trying to understand the exact behavior of value initialization by `T()` or `T{}` for a class type `T` in C++11.
What confuses me are these two snippets taken from http://en.cppreference.com:

[Value Initialization:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> The effects of value initialization are:
>   [...]
>
> 1) if T is a class type with **no default constructor** or with a user-provided or **deleted default constructor**, the object is default-initialized;
>       (since C++11)
>
> [...]

so I looked up [Default-Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization):

> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> - if T is a [...] class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is **one of the default constructors**) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;
>
> [...]

So this basically says that if T is a class type and its implicit default constructor is not available, then the object will be constructed by a call to one of its default constructors? In my understanding, this makes only sense for the mentioned case of a user-provided default constructor; then, upon construction, only what is explicitly stated in that constructor will be executed, and every member not explicitly initialized will get default-initialized (please correct me if I am wrong here).

**My questions:**

1) What would happen if there was **no user-provided default constructor** and there was no default constructor or it was deleted? I would guess the code would not compile. If this is right, then:

2) What is the need to also **explicitly mention** the cases "no default constructor" and "deleted default constructor"?

Comment: should it be *"defaulted default constructor"* ?

Answer (score 2):

The wording on cppreference doesn't seem to match that in the standard. C++11 8.5/7 [dcl.init]:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
>     default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default
>     constructor);
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>     is zero-initialized and, if `T`’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>     called.
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> An object that is value-initialized is deemed to be constructed and thus subject to provisions of this International
>   Standard applying to “constructed” objects, objects “for which the constructor has completed,” etc.,
>   even if no constructor is invoked for the object’s initialization.

For comparison, this is the wording in C++14 (n4140) 8.5/7 [dcl.init]:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a
>     default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then
>     the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if
>     `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> An object that is value-initialized is deemed to be constructed and thus subject to provisions of this International
>   Standard applying to “constructed” objects, objects “for which the constructor has completed,” etc.,
>   even if no constructor is invoked for the object’s initialization.

Comment: Does that value initialisation happens when there is no default constructor..?? Isn’t it compiler error.?

Comment: @setia_ The first bullet point (the one with user-provided constructors) says: "and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor". Or did you mean the C++14 version? That one declares it ill-formed "indirectly" by delegating to default-initialisation (which is ill-formed when there's no usable default ctor).