# Could a class type with deleted default constructor be default initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer

From what cppref says about [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or **deleted default constructor**, the object is **default-initialized**;

But since that class type has **deleted default constructor**, how could the object be default-initialized?

As far as I know, **default initialization** of class type needs the access of default constructor. If we have:

```
struct A {
    A() = delete;
    int k;
};
```

Then `A *a = new A;` will fail, so does `A* a = new A();`.

But `A a{};` is OK. But why? According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> Otherwise, If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type **with a default constructor**, value-initialization is performed.

Comment: Working example: https://godbolt.org/g/f8CWAF

Comment: @RichardCritten : That's on the right path, but that's not value-initialization, it's list-initialization. :-]

Comment: @RichardCritten See my newly edited post.This still requires a accessible default constructor. So I do not know why `A a{}` could work here.

Comment: @ildjarn, you're right, sorry about that; change `foo f{10};` to `foo f{};`.

Comment: Related to [value-initialization-of-class-object-without-default-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317527/value-initialization-of-class-object-without-default-constructor).

Comment: @Jarod42 It seems like the wording of c++11 is reasonable, but the wording of c++14 is the same with what I've quoted.

Comment: I think "value-initialization is performed" should not be intended as "value-initialization will succeed" but rather as "value-initialization is attempted". I think in the case of deleted default constructor it would only succeed (i.e. compile) for POD types. But I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: If you're going to talk about the specifics of a class, it's helfpul to at least provide what that class definition looks like. I have no idea what you imagine `A` to be like.

Comment: @Barry Sorry, but the standard also doesn't specify  a class.

Comment: @bigxiao I don't see how that's relevant to what I said.

Comment: @Barry I mean that since the standard does not specify a class, so it's a common rule for all classes. Therefore I did not specify a concrete class here.

Comment: @bigxiao "`A a{}` is OK" is not a common rule for all classes.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for your reminding, I've added the definition.

Comment: Note [this was fixed w/ P1008](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/997532065166917635)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the standard just means "if `T` is a class type with deleted default constructor then goto default initialization". It would fail at last because the constructor selected for default initialization is deleted. It's used to distinguish with the 2nd case, i.e. "if `T` is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted", for that case zero-initialization is performed firstly, then default-initialization if `T` has a non-trivial default constructor.

> `A a{}` is OK,but why?

Because when `A` is an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) aggregate initialization is performed. Note that explicitly deleted constructors are allowed for aggregate type since C++11.

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.

And

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - ...
> - class type (typically, `struct` or `union`), that has
>
>   - ...
>   - no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++17) (until C++20)
>   - ...

**EDIT**

Since C++20 the behavior changed; `A a{};` would fail.

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - ...
> - class type (typically, `struct` or `union`), that has
>
>   - ...
>   - no user-declared or inherited constructors (since C++20)
>   - ...

`A` is not an aggregate again. `A a{};` performs [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) ([default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)), the deleted constructor is used and fails.

Comment: Is `A a{}` well-formed here?

Comment: @bigxiao Yes if `A` is an aggregate type.

Comment: The cppref says _"If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is **completely empty** , the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their **default initializers** "_ . But since `A` has no default cotr, I think the initialization `A a{}` should fail consequently.

Comment: The sentence above is directly quoted in the page of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Comment: @bigxiao It says "the remaining members...", i.e. initializing `A`'s member, not `A` itself.

Comment: So what about `A` itself? I cannot find anything about that. Does that mean the standard just omits `A` itself?

Comment: @bigxiao 1) `A` is value initialized; 2) Because `A` is an aggregate it's aggregate initialized; 3) In the process of aggregate initialization, all the members of `A` are value initialized; 4) Done. That's the whole process of `A`'s initialization, is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah, I seems to know what is happening on earth.

Comment: Note [this was fixed w/ P1008](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/997532065166917635)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That's a big change of aggregate initialization. Will it be adopted?

Comment: @songyuanyao if you look at the next tweet in the thread, you see the main author of the paper saying it is merged into C++20 :-)

Comment: @songyuanyao The change to aggregates has been added to C++20 so code like this will no longer compile.  Would you mind updated the answer with that info?  I can as well if you don't have the time.  I only ask as I'm using this post as a dupe target.

Answer (score 8):

> But since that class type has deleted default constructor, how could the object be default-initialized?

Stating that the object is default-initialized doesn't in of itself imply that default-initialization is a valid thing to do. The wording just forwards us into that process, it makes the initialization process coherent, it doesn't imply that it must succeed.

For instance:

```
struct A {
    A() = delete;
    A(int); // not an aggregate
};

auto a = A();
```

The initializer is `()`, so this the object is [value-initialized](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.4). In this case, that means it's [default-initialized](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.1), which means we [find a constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7.1).

Calling that constructor happens to be [ill-formed](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct.def.delete-2.sentence-1), because it's deleted, which makes the whole initialization ill-formed. But we get to that point by way of default-initialization.